# How to get the date of the first and last day of a week

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query who gives me the week number.

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'iw') week from dual
```

I would like to retrieve the first and last date, like this: 2019-11-11 to 2019-11-17.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to use `trunc()`:

```
select trunc(sysdate, 'iw') as week_start,
       trunc(sysdate, 'iw') + interval '6' day as week_end       
from dual
```